# How to create local module directory in jenkis using tfs?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I was create jenkins new job and created local module but it gave me an error like this:

"Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\abc

Checking out a fresh workspace because C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace
\abc\$\myspeace\myversion doesn't exist

Cleaning local Directory $/myspeace/myversion ".

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you changed the Local workfolder and Workspace name in Jenkins configuration. You may try the default setting as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

Detailed information, check https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin